# Draw a graph of the following sinusoidal situation. Then write an equation in the form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Draw a graph of the following sinusoidal situation. Then write an equation in the form 
$\displaystyle y\,\, = \,\,a\cos {{2\pi \left( {t\,\, - \,\,c} \right)} \over p}\,\, + \,\,b$

```
    The high tide in a harbour occurs at 2:30 am and the depth at high tide is 16 metres. 
    8.4 hours later the low tide occurs. The depth of low tide is 4 metres.
```

[image]

Comment: Trying to solve a question simlar to this.. would appreciate if someone could explain how to do this with a solution step by step :) much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Since high tide is $16$ and low tide is $4$, the amplitude is half the difference, which gives us $a=\dfrac{16-4}{2}=6$. By taking the average, the "middle" tide corresponds to the vertical displacement of the graph, giving us $b=\dfrac{4+16}{2}=10$. Note that 1 period occurs after we go from high tide, to low tide, then back to high tide. Thus, by symmetry, we have $p=2(8.4)=16.8$.

Now assume that $t$ represent the number of hours that have passed after $12$am (midnight). Then since high tide occurs at $2$:$30$am, we know that the graph contains the point $(2.5, 16)$. Hence, since the graph of $y=\cos x$ contains the point $(0,1)$, the phase shift must be $c=2.5$.

This gives us the equation:

> $$
> y=6\cos{\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{16.8}(x-2.5) \right)}+10
> $$

You can see how Wolfram|Alpha plots this [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=y=6%5Ccos%7B%5Cleft%28%5Cdfrac%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7B16.8%7D%28x-2.5%29%20%5Cright%29%7D%2b10). The important points you need to plot are:

> - $(2.5, 16)$
> - $(6.7, 10)$
> - $(10.9, 4)$
> - $(15.1, 10)$
> - $(19.3, 16)$

where the $x$-coordinates increase by a quarter of the period each time and the $y$-coordinates oscillate from its max to its min then back to its max.